# Django multi input form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a template that looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url ... %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table class="table">
    {% for x in X %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{x.id}}"" /></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</form>
```

What type of field should I use in the django form class for the checkboxes ?

Thanks for the answers

EDIT:

I did not mention, X in loop is given at runtime. It is not a list of predefined values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `CheckBoxMultipleSelect` widget for the form field.

E.g.

```
def MyForm(forms.Form):
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
        widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES)
    ...
```

Reference: [Widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/)

Comment: It works, but I cannot rate your answer, I have only 11 points. Thank you.

Comment: @MateiFlorescu Good to know that. You can rate later once you get enough points. However, you can accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
CUSTOMERTYPE = (
    (u'-', u'-'),
    (u'Single', u'Single Customer'),
    (u'Community', u'Community Change'),
)
CustomerType = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CUSTOMERTYPE)
```